# Searching in MVC5 using linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Using this Linq code I get any values corresponding to the search input i.e if I search `country = Italy` and `gender = female` I get both employees from Italy and employees who are female but I need it to be more specific. 
i.e if I search `Country = Italy` and `Gender = female` I need to get female employees from Italy. Please suggest me a Linq code for the same

Also, I have five search inputs (First Name, Last Name, Designation, Country, Gender) so just (`&&`) only doesn't do the work here!

Here's the code:

```
List<Employee> Elist = userdb.Employees
    .Where(i => i.FirstName == Fn || 
                i.LastName == Ln || 
                i.Designation == desig ||
                i.Country == country || 
                i.Gender == gender)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Just use and (&&) instead of or (||)

Comment: If I use (&&) I need to enter all the search inputs (in my case I have 5 of them. I just used two inputs for demo here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you are not wanting to include criteria that is not filled in. You would only want to filter by a value if the value exists (or is not null). Use an IQueryable to build your search and then assign it to Elist.

```
IQueryable<Employee> Query = userdb.Employees;

if (Fn != null) {
    Query = Query.Where(i => i.FirstName.Equals(Fn));
}

if (Ln != null) {
    Query = Query.Where(i => i.LastName.Equals(Ln));
}

if (desig != null) {
    Query = Query.Where(i => i.Designation.Equals(desig));
}

if (country != null) {
    Query = Query.Where(i => i.Country.Equals(country));
}

if (gender != null) {
    Query = Query.Where(i => i.Gender.Equals(gender));
}

List<Employee> Elist = Query.ToList();
```

Comment: So, what I posted 5 minutes ago? :)

Comment: Yep... Curse my slow typing.

Comment: @DavidG, but not quite as good, because I didn't include the link about deferred query execution.

Answer (score 3):

This is a situation where the nature of [`IQueryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=netframework-4.8) comes in very useful. You can add `Where` clauses to your query without actually executing anything against the database. The SQL would only be executed when you materialise the data, for example using `ToList()`. This is called [deferred query execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution#deferred-query-execution).
So you can write your code like this:

```
IQueryable<Employee> query = userdb.Employees;

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Fn))
{
    query = query.Where(e => e.FirstName == Fn);
}

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ln))
{
    query = query.Where(e => e.LastName == Ln);
}

// etc. etc.

List<Employee> Elist = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use a PredicateBuilder here. A small example, let's say you just have 2 queries:

```
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> hasFirstName = p1 => p1.FirstName == Fn;

Expression<Func<Person, bool>> hasLastName= p2 => p2.LastName == Ln";
```

You could build this into a predicate builder like so and keep on expanding using any sort of logic:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Employee>();  

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Fn))  
{  
    predicate = predicate.And(e => e.FirstName == Fn);
}  

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ln))  
{  
    predicate = predicate.And(e => e.FirstName == Ln);
}  

var result = userdb.Employees.Where(predicate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<Employee> Elist = userdb.Employees
.Where(i => (Fn == null || i.FirstName == Fn ) && 
            (Ln == null || i.LastName == Ln ) && 
            (desig == null || i.Designation == desig) &&
            (country == null || i.Country == country) && 
            (gender == null || i.Gender == gender)
.ToList();
```